# How can I parse data from GET response in proper way?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json, get

I was trying to parse response data from web server. I am using Xcode 4.2.

```
NSLog(@"Establishing connection...");
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]; [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"example.com/test.php"]]; [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
accept = @"Kokokoko";
NSLog(@"Adding value for HTTP Header");
[request addValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept"];

NSLog(@"Sending request...");
//send request & get response
returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"Request sent");
```

Then I want to use returnData to parse JSON response. It should be

```
["Test", "42", "OK"]
```

So I was trying to use NSDictionary and JSONValue and other tricks but I was not succeed. Maybe there is a simple solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you expect your server to return a string like that:

```
["Test", "42", "OK"]
```

Then the JSONValue of it would be NSArray (not NSDictionary). Try this:

```
NSString* responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

NSLog(@"Response String: %@", responseString);

// Supposing that you are using SBJson, the parsing part may look like this:
//
NSArray* responseArray = [returnString JSONValue];

NSLog(@"Response Array: %@", responseArray);
```